# Accessing elements of large array

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I'm having a problem accessing elements of one of my arrays. I apologize beforehand for the long code, but it's necessary to fully explain the problem. I have a struct which I've declared in a header file as follows:

```
typedef struct {
    // DC the current value of the Program Counter register
    unsigned short int DC;

    // PSR : Processor Status Register, bit[0] = P, bit[1] = Z, bit[2] = N, bit[15] = privilege bit
    unsigned short int GSR;

    //Registers - 8
    unsigned short int R[8];

    //Control signals 
    ControlSignals control_signals;

    //Memory 
    unsigned short int mem[65536];
} MachineState;
```

In the linker file, I am reading from a binary file and storing 16 bit hex values to the `memory` struct array. Here is the relevant setup for that operation:

```
//Rectify endianness
        if ((foo_array[0]) == 0xDECA || (foo_array[0]) == 0xB7C3 || (foo_array[0]) == 0x7EF1 || (foo_array[0]) == 0x5E71)
        {
            //Iterate through each element in array, swapping bytes to convert to big endian
            for (i = 0; i < bytes; i++)
            {
                //Swap bytes
                (foo_array[i]) = ((foo_array[i])>>8) | ((foo_array[i])<<8);
            }
        }

        //Iterate through temp array selecting only CADE/DADA instructions to copy to struct array
        for (i = 0; i < bytes; i++)
        {
            if ((foo_array[i]) == 0xCADE || (foo_array[i]) == 0xDADA)
            {

                //Increment to starting address
                i++;

                //Store start address
                start_address = foo_array[i];

                //Increment to n-body word specification
                i++;

                //Find number of words in relevant instructions
                foo = foo_array[i];

                //Increment to beginning of instruction
                i++;

                //Iterate through temp array selecting only CADE/DADA instructions to copy to struct array
                for (count = 0, j = start_address; count < foo; i++, j++, count++)
                {

                    //Assign values from temp array to machine memory array
                    machine->mem[j] = foo_array[i];
                    printf("address %05d in memory is: 0x%04X\n",j, machine->mem[j] );                          
                }

                //Once loop exited, decrement index variable to appropriate values
                if (count == foo)
                {
                    i--;
                }
            }   
        }
```

As you might imagine, in the output to machine memory, there would be hex values, some zero, and non-zero as follows:

```
address 32805 in memory is: 0x0201
address 32806 in memory is: 0x0000
address 32807 in memory is: 0x8000
address 32808 in memory is: 0x0000
address 33280 in memory is: 0x9E00
address 33281 in memory is: 0x8000
address 40960 in memory is: 0x0001
```

The values I've stored in the array need to be passed into a function to be operated on, however I can't figure out a way to pass **all** those values that have populated the array. The array is long, from index 0x0000 to 0x10000, yet the only way I've figured to pass in all values is in a for-loop, selecting for when I hit the fist non-zero element in the array, but the problem is, zero values are also very important and must also be used. This is my implementation for the loop so far:

```
 //Iterate through each element passing populated elements into function
        for (i = 0; i < (sizeof(machine.mem)) / (sizeof(unsigned short int)); i++)
        {
          //  printf("index is %d\n",i );
            if (machine.mem[i] != 0)
            {        
                printf("machine memory is: 0x%04X\n",machine.mem[i] );

                //Call UpdateMachineState to begin decoding machine instructions and execute one LC4 datapath
               //UpdateMachineState(&machine);   
            }
        }
```

It allows me to find only nonzero values, but what if the starting number or middle values in the array were zero? They would be completely missed. Is there a way to obtain all populated values? I just can't seem to figure this out.

EDIT:
It would seem from the comments received that it might not be clear what the actual problem is so I will try my best to clarify. After loading to machine memory its contents are as follows:

```
address 00000 in memory is: 0xF020
address 00001 in memory is: 0x9A00
address 00002 in memory is: 0xDBA0
address 00003 in memory is: 0x7B40
address 00004 in memory is: 0xF0FF
address 32800 in memory is: 0x9600
address 32801 in memory is: 0xD7A0
address 32802 in memory is: 0x9802
address 32803 in memory is: 0x78C0
address 32804 in memory is: 0x64C0
address 32805 in memory is: 0x0201
address 32806 in memory is: 0x0000
address 32807 in memory is: 0x8000
address 32808 in memory is: 0x0000
address 33280 in memory is: 0x9E00
address 33281 in memory is: 0x8000
address 40960 in memory is: 0x0001
```

Here index 00000 is the start address and index 40960 is the end address. The problem is that I don't know how to set up the for-loop so that can I pass in all the contents that have been loaded into the machine.mem struct into the function  `UpdateMachineState(&machine);` if there are elements contained that contain the value 0x0000 (address 32806 and 32808 for example). When the struct machine.mem is declared, all its values are automatically set to zero so I'm not sure how to discriminate between the pre-set 0x0000 values and those that were loaded here: `machine->mem[j] = foo_array[i]`. I can post the complete code if necessary.

Comment: are sure that (sizeof(machine.memory)) / (sizeof(unsigned short int)) is correct, loop should print all items if size is ok without your mem[i]!= 0,

Comment: consider using(sizeof(machine.mem))  / (sizeof(machine.mem[0] )

Comment: What is `memory` and how does it relate to `mem`? Please copy and paste your rea code.

Comment: It isn't quite clear what the problem is. Are you trying to get all non-zero values from an array for free? That's not possible, you need to iterate over the array and check each value. If you want all non-zero values in an array, you need to copy them over to *another* array, one by one.

Comment: Please make a [mcve] to demonstrate. Your shown code is not complete, not verifiable. I suspect it is not minimal either, some effort would probably allow to demonstrate the problem though leaving out some of the shown code.

Comment: @n.m. I have made edits to the question. I can post complete code if it would help in further understanding the problem. Also, memory was an error and should be mem. I have changed it accordingly.

Comment: @nima_moradi, your suggestion to use sizeof(machine.mem[0]) is equivalent to sizeof(unsigned short int) because the struct machine.mem is first declared as an unsigned short int

Comment: @nima_moradi, actually on second thought, is there a way to select for any element values of 2 bytes in the for-loop? That might solve my problem?

Comment: If I understand it right, your file has several memory *ranges* filled with data, and you want to copy just these ranges to the `mem` array and still be able to distinguish between locations that were copied and locations that were not touched. If so you better think of a different strategy.

Comment: @nima_moradi yes that is the primary issue holding me back now and I'm not sure how to select for those ranges without just selecting for non-zero entries which I don't want to do.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "select for those ranges", but if you want to work with a set of memory ranges, you need a data type that represents a memory range, and some kind of container that is able to hold several such values.

Answer (score 1):

> When the struct machine.mem is declared, all its values are
>   automatically set to zero so I'm not sure how to discriminate between
>   the pre-set 0x0000 values and those that were loaded here:
>   machine->mem[j] = foo_array[i].

You can create a struct that includes a flag with the memory value and set the flag when the memory value is assigned.

Like this:

```
typedef struct{
    unsigned short int value;
    bool value_assigned;
}mem_t;
```

Then when you declare the MachineState struct you just declare mem as an array of those structs like so:

```
typedef struct {
    // DC the current value of the Program Counter register
    unsigned short int DC;

    // PSR : Processor Status Register, bit[0] = P, bit[1] = Z, bit[2] = N, bit[15] = privilege bit
    unsigned short int GSR;

    //Registers - 8
    unsigned short int R[8];

    //Control signals 
    ControlSignals control_signals;

    //Memory 
    mem_t mem[65536];
} MachineState;
```

Then in the portion of your code where you are assigning the memory value, you just have to be sure to set that flag.

```
//Iterate through temp array selecting only CADE/DADA instructions to copy to struct array
for (count = 0, j = start_address; count < foo; i++, j++, count++)
{

    //Assign values from temp array to machine memory array
    machine->mem[j].value = foo_array[i];
    machine->mem[j].value_assigned = true;
    printf("address %05d in memory is: 0x%04X\n",j, machine->mem[j]);

}
```

Now you should be able to iterate back through that array and check for `value_assigned == true`